# vectorize non aligned data in a struct method

Tags: c++

I have this simple struct:

```
struct cbt
{
    vector<vector<int>> tree; 
    int depth;
    int data;

    cbt(int max_size) // just initializes tree
    {
        depth = (int) log2(max_size);
        unsigned int l; 

        for(int i = 0; i <= depth; i++)
        {
            l = (unsigned int) pow(2,i);
            tree.push_back(vector<int>(l,0));
        }
     }

      inline void update(int pos, int value)
      { 
          int diff = value - data;
          int p = pos>>1;

          for(int i = depth; i >= 0; i--)
          {
              tree[i][p] += diff;
              p = p>>1;
          }
      }

};
```

Is there any way to vectorize the loop in the `update()` function even thought the data is not aligned?

In my code the `update()` function is called billions of times and so I was hoping to make it as fast as possible.

Comment: I think we'll need to see how `update` is called.

Comment: Aside: No need for `update` to be `inline`.

Comment: Aside: `l = 1 << i`; or even `unsigned int l = 1;` and then `l *= 2;` in the loop.

Comment: If it's being called billions of times, I'm thinking it often doesn't need to update. Second line, if (!diff) return;

Comment: If you are concerned at all with performance, first remove that `vector<vector<int>>` and make your data cache-friendly.

Comment: `pow(2,i);` is another time-waster and it can be dangerous. `pow` is designed to handle really nasty computations like pi to the power of e and using it to compute exponents of 2 is overkill. Look into bit shifting for a much faster approach. The dangerous part is `pow` operates on floating point numbers. Floating point numbers are imprecise and the conversion back to integer often results in small errors becoming very noticeable.

Comment: `cbt(int max_size)
    {
        depth = (int) log2(max_size);` better: `cbt(int max_size) : depth(static_cast<int>(log2(max_size)) {` - always use the initialization list when you can - and don't use C-style casts.

Comment: @spectras can you please elaborate more on that? I re implemented the struct with raw pointer so I don't have memory fragmentation but the performance is exactly the   same.

Comment: @somename `vector` is basically two pointers (3 actually to track capacity). So `vector<vector<T>>` points to an area that contains pointers that themselves point to `T`s. So the `T`s themselves are scattered around the heap. Even worst, the cpu cannot know where until it has read the pointers from the vector of vectors.